# What video card drivers are needed to play Minecraft with an integrated Intel GPU on Windows 8?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, windows-8

I have installed Windows 8 Pro and realized Minecraft doesn't work, and have found a tutorial to find out my device info. What drivers are required with this video card?

Manufacturer: Intel Corporation
Device Name: Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator 3150
Date: 7/25/2012 8:30:14 PM
Model: WDDM 1.0

Comment: This is an IGP (Integrated Graphics Processor). While I doubt an IGP would have difficulties rendering a game such as Minecraft, IGPs are usually the reason why games refuse to work. If in doubt, you may try this site: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?toplevelcategory=Support%2FSPT+Downloads+%26+Drivers&storeKeyword=Intel+Graphics+Media+Accelerator+3150+%28Intel+GMA+3150%29&lstLanguages=en_us&contenttype=&advanced=false&editAdvanced=false&allwords=Intel+Graphics+Media+Accelerator+3150+%28Intel+GMA+3150%29&exactwords=&nonewords=&topicarea=

Comment: Have you looked at: http://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements

Comment: why so many down votes?

Answer (score 3):

Many graphics card manufacturers have not yet published updated drivers for Windows 8. Windows 8 comes with default drivers written by Microsoft that will make *most* GPUs work, but only enough to run Windows itself. These drivers are not made by the GPU manufacturer, so they don't use the hardware very well and provide only the most basic graphical functions to software that wants to use the GPU. Minecraft can't run on a computer with these default drivers.

So the short answer is, for some GPUs there *are* no Windows 8–compatible drivers that will run Minecraft. Not yet. And if it's a niche GPU, then maybe never.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend purchasing a new Graphics Unit as the one you currently have is Integrated. While this may work, using Integrated Graphics Cards can prove to be an issue when attempting to run high-end games.

Comment: Well, when I run Minecraft I get a crash error saying Bad Video Card Drivers

Comment: @apotter96 I noticed that in your previous question. I advised the same answer in regards to this. As your Graphics Card is Integrated, you are unable to update - thus forcing you to purchase a new one if you wish to run MineCraft (or any other high-performance game for that matter).

Comment: @apotter96 Have you tried the link I provided you with in my comment? One of the results you'll find there are bound to lead you to the most up-to-date drivers for your IGP. `if you wish to run MineCraft (or any other high-performance game for that matter)` I highly doubt, Minecraft can be considered "high-performance", tbh.

Comment: @Nolonar well I know that, being pixelated and all... I was just making **apotter96** aware just incase a newer game is bought and the same issue is experienced.

Comment: I would imagine Minecraft is more CPU-intensive than anything, but agreed - if it is possible to upgrade your GPU (can't on some laptops) then it's a good investment.

Comment: @Alex That's a fair point. I'm not sure as to whether it's RAM intensive or not, but certainly an upgrade on the system would be advisable.

Comment: @Nolonar Minecraft is actually very graphically demanding. (Also CPU and RAM demanding.) Just because it paints the world with pixellated art assets doesn't mean it's simple to actually render those thousands upon thousands of blocks. It's also not a AAA title that has been carefully optimised—its rendering code is actually fairly inefficient, and needs good hardware to make up for it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie My original point proven.