# Minecraft Graphics Card

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

so whenever I open minecraft, I log in and it tells me minecraft has crashed because of a bad video card driver.  I have an intel driver and it is up to date, the issue is that i'm running the video driver that was given with windows 8 as default.  Can anyone please tell me the intel series needed for windows 8 to run minecraft?

Comment: There's no such thing as "the intel graphics driver for windows 8". If you go to the Windows 8 equivalent of Device Manager and open up display adaptors and find the name of the graphics device and edit that into your question (or pop it into Google) you may have better luck.

Comment: The problem of having an integrated Intel card that stops running Minecraft after installing Windows 8 is common and already been asked here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/114370/what-video-card-drivers-are-needed-to-play-minecraft-with-this-device-info

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's... really silly to propose closing this as a duplicate of a question closed as _Too Localized_ of all the things.

Comment: @badp Unless I disagree with the too-local close on the other question, you mean. :) But yes, I do appreciate the irony. I just think we should have one general "Intel card + Win8 + Minecraft = no worky" question to deal with these.

Comment: @sev so where is your reopen vote?

Comment: @badp There it goes. I was hesitating because it could use an edit and I wasn't sure how to attack it, but that isn't urgent I suppose.